# Make a div grow as wide as possible

Tags: css

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="outerContent">
    <div id="tabBar">This element is always at the top, defined as block, and 70% width. Also is centered.</div>
    <div id="leftSide">This is a left side bar.</div>
    <div id="content">The actual page content.</div>
    <div id="rightSide">Sidebar ont he right.</div>
</div>
```

`#outerContent` defines all its sibling divs to float left, be `inline-block`s and by itself has `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to `auto` - so it's centered.

I would like to know if it is possible to automatically stretch `#content` to the widest possible. Currently, I have it set to 70% of width, the other elements to 10% with a `margin-right` to make some space between the elements.

This is meant to use less PHP. I am in a Yii application and would like to keep my design fluent, so I don't need to use a lot of PHP code just to assign the correct IDs. I am using the latest Bootstrap/JQuery in my code as well, if that could be helpful.

Comment: the answer is yes, but you should show your CSS to see what you got

Comment: can you create a demo of code using jsfiddle.net and share? That will be more helpful!

Comment: @UID: My CSS and markup: http://jsfiddle.net/qbkxeLp1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right, you'll like to make your side totally responsive in width by using the hole space in your content wrapper. I modified your fiddle and made margin's dynamic. http://jsfiddle.net/qbkxeLp1/2/ Now you are able to minimize and upsize your website without losing any of your floating position in border-box-model.

#### I edited margins and width of:

```
#content {
    width: 64%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: That is very interesting. But I was looking to make `#content` spread all the way out when `#leftSide` and `#rightSide` are empty/not present without using some PHP code. Is that possible? Thanks for that CSS though, very impressive! It's going into the code still.

Comment: Yes, its possible with JavaScript & PHP and maybe also CSS. But i would preffer a solution with PHP cause .. if its "empty", and your view is rendered by PHP anyway, let PHP build your view, and also let PHP decide displaying or hide `#leftSide' and '#rightSide' .

Comment: I did go with the PHP aproach in the end. Still put in your CSS as it makes the design seem much more fluent now. Thanks again. :)

Comment: You are welcome, and more welcome if you tick my answer as right ;)